# angular textarea data is NaN

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why text area data is not working with ng-bind while working with ng-model?

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">

  <div id="out">
    {{objInput}}
  </div>

  <div id="out2" ng-bind="out2"></div>

</div>
```

Here is plnkr 
http://plnkr.co/edit/srYQnpHudt7gfeOXN1ff?p=preview

Comment: use `$scope.out2 = JSON.stringify($scope.objInput)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only assign the `txt` variable when the controller is instantiated. 
You can do:

```
$scope.generate = function (){
    $scope.out2 = JSON.stringify($scope.objInput);  
};
```

or, you can assing the `txt` inside the function:

```
$scope.generate = function (){
  var txt  = $scope.objInput;
  $scope.out2 = JSON.stringify(txt);
  console.log(txt); 
};
```

or, send `txt` as the function param:

```
<button id="gJson" class="form-control btn btn-primary" ng-click="generate(objInput)"> Write</button>


$scope.generate = function (txt){
  $scope.out2 = JSON.stringify(txt);
  console.log(txt);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="out2" ng-bind="objInput"></div>
```

So, you need to use, the property name `objInput` in ng-bind.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you only assign the txt variable when the controller is created. If you move the variable into the generate function it works.

```
$scope.generate = function() {
  var txt = $scope.objInput;
  $scope.out2 += JSON.stringify(txt);
  console.log(txt);
};
```

Comment: Thank You. But now it is adding the word "undefined". Why is this  happening? Would you mind to explain? 

http://plnkr.co/edit/srYQnpHudt7gfeOXN1ff?p=preview

Comment: I'm guessing that comes from the fact that `$scope.out2` is not defined when the first `+=` action is performed. try setting `$scope.out2 = "";` before the function declaration. http://plnkr.co/edit/460RQliNdjDTa7O5aVUZ?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value to txt only in the controller initialization. When the value of objInput changes then you have to change the txt value as well. In this case you can make use of a watch function and then change the txt value.

Code:

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('cApp', []);
app.controller('cCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.objInput = '';
    var txt  = $scope.objInput;
    $scope.$watch('objInput', function(oldValue,newValue) {
      txt = newValue;
    })
        $scope.generate = function (){
    $scope.out2 = JSON.stringify(txt);
        console.log(txt);

        };
});// Fin qCtrl
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
})();
```

[Updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zfCWKrHDe4q2jNTmQV9h?p=preview)

[More on watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope/#$watch)

Comment: You shouldn't be using a `$watch` just for this. `$watch` is a bad idea in general and should be avoided

Comment: @RazvanBalosin: Showcasing $watch functionality over here and how it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" ng-model="objInput"></textarea>
    <button id="gJson" class="form-control btn btn-primary" ng-click="generate(objInput)"> Write</button>
  </div>    
<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
    <div id="out">
      {{objInput}}
    </div>
    <div ng-bind="out2"></div>
  </div>
```

JS :

```
    (function() {
  var app = angular.module('cApp', []);
  app.controller('cCtrl', function($scope) {
    var txt = $scope.objInput;
    $scope.generate = function(txt) {
      $scope.out2 = txt;
    };
  }); 
})();
```

Try this